# mouse click not working in Ubuntu and Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, xubuntu

I have been using Xubuntu and Ubuntu on our older home PC for almost 2 years without much trouble until today when the mouse seemed to not work properly.

I can move the pointer around and click but after a while the left and right click does not work. I can hover over a button and clicking shows the visual effect of lowering the button but it won't respond with the action required. It seems to happen sooner when opening a firefox window, but is not restricted to firefox.

I have looked on this forum and others for advice and I have tried the following:

- compiz --replace
- metacity --replace
- I have even reinstalled the Xserver

I checked the `xinput` to see if the buttons were not assigned but everything seems OK. I am on the 3.2.0-54 kernel and running Xubuntu/Ubuntu 12.01. And I have tried different mice on different USB ports and they all do the same thing. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Help out there anyone? :)

Comment: I guess if I don't get any help from the community I would be forced to reinstall everything..... A pity.

Answer (score 1):

A distribution upgrade was what was needed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I don't know how but my previous kernel must have been corrupted.